# I want to validate when date and time selected is past current date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, time, format

I have two readonly textboxes, one textbox is linked with the jquery datepicker and the other textbox is linked with the timepicker jquery. Now the great thing about the jquery datepicker is that I can range my dates so that the user cannot select any dates before the current date. But the Jquery timepicker cannot be ranged so the time is before the current time.

Because of this there is a possbile chance that the user can select the current date but a time before the current time. Obviously this means the time chosen has passed the current time of the current day which I don't want happening. So a validation is needed where if date textbox and time textbox is past the current date and time, then a message is displayed stating "The Date and Time you have selected is before the Current Date and Time" else if time and date together is past current date and time then display "".

How can I do this. Below is my best attempt at it but I couldn't get it to work.

```
<head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Create a Session</title>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

     function validation() {
                    var dateTextO = document.getElementById("datepicker");
                    var timeTextO = document.getElementById("timepicker");
                    var errDateTimeMsgO = document.getElementById("dateTimeAlert")

    var currentDate = new Date()
        var day = currentDate.getDate()
        var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
        var year = currentDate.getFullYear()

        var currentTime = new Date()
        var hours = currentTime.getHours()
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
        if (minutes < 10){
        minutes = "0" + minutes
        }
        if (hours < 10){
        hours = "0" + hours
        }

        if((dateTextO < currentDate) && (timeTextO < currentTime)){
            errDateTimeMsgO.innerHTML = "The Date and Time you have selected is before the Current Date and Time";
        } else {
            errDateTimeMsgO.innerHTML = "";
        }

            }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="create_session.php" method="post" name="sessionform">
    <p><strong>4: Date:</strong> <input type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly"></p>
                <p><strong>5: Time:</strong> <input type="text" id="timepicker" readonly="readonly"><span class="timepicker_button_trigger"><img src="Images/clock.gif" alt="Decrease" /></span></p>
                <div id="dateTimeAlert"></div>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the date generated by `new Date()`  is something like this

```
Wed Jul 20 2011 19:09:46 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

but your datepicker time maybe something like this

```
28-07-2011
```

those are in two different formats . so you can not comapare , so you have to get those to one format

```
var checkindatestr = document.getElementById("datepicker");
var dateParts = checkindatestr.split("-");

var checkindate = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);
var now = new Date();
var difference = now - checkindate;
```

you can find difference of the 2 days this way .

i ll find a way and tell you how to compare 2 times.........  :D

**UPDATE**

```
    var checkindatestr = document.getElementById("datepicker"); 
    var dateParts = checkindatestr.split("-");  
    var checkindate = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]); 
    var nowdate = new Date(); 
    var differenceDate = parseInt(nowdate) - parseInt(checkindate); 

    var checkintimestr = document.getElementById("timepicker"); 
    var timeParts = checkindatestr.split(":"); 

    var currentTime = new Date(); 
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

    if(( differenceDate >= 0) && (parseInt(hours) >= parseInt(timeParts[0]))  && (parseInt(minutes) > parseInt(timeParts[1]) )){
        errDateTimeMsgO.innerHTML = "The Date and Time you have selected is before the Current Date and Time";
    } else {
        errDateTimeMsgO.innerHTML = "";
    }

        }
```

Comment: what is the format your time-picker time , give me an example

Comment: hmm . you know how to get current hour and minute , so get the value from document.getElementById("timepicker"); and split it an compare it with you hour and time portions . try it , if you have any probs tell me .........

Comment: An example of the timepicker time : 14:35. By the way the code you have gave me for the 2 days, does that suppose to replace the code I have at the moment which finds current date?

Comment: Still nothing, I like to say that because it is 5am in the uk where I live, I am picking hours which begin with 0 e.g. 01:30 or 02:15. Is the var hours and var minutes being displayed in the right format? I tried to get it the right format and this can be seen in the update which I have editted after I tried your update

Comment: var differenceDate = nowdate - checkindate ; differenceDate >= 0 means nowadate is greater than checkindate

Comment: instead of differenceDate use  parseInt(differenceDate) and to all other variables in if(( differenceDate >= 0) && (hours >= timeParts[0])  && (minutes > timeParts[1] )){
  shoul be wrapped in parseInt

Comment: also var differenceDate = nowdate - checkindate;  shoul be     var differenceDate = parseInt(nowdate) - parseInt(checkindate);

Comment: It isn't giving away any errors, it is just that when I select today's date but I select a previous time, lets says 08:30 (in uk its 11:00 now) then it should displsy the message but it isn't. Please look at this link 'http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php'. This is where I found out how to get current date and time, could this help you?

Comment: Actually just found a new error when I clciked on the button, it states this is not a function: var dateParts = checkindatestr.split("-");